# How to make a package optional in an angular component?

Tags: angular

I have an angular form component, that I import into other projects as a library, and re-use it.
I use Angular 15. In this form component, I have got a loading-template with a spinner in it, like this:

```
<ng-template #loadingTemplate>
  <slot name="customLoading">
    <vfg-spinner></vfg-spinner>
  </slot>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #errorTemplate>
  <slot name="customError">
    Error failed loading Form<br/>
  </slot>
</ng-template>
<div>
...
</div>
```

In my form module, I import it like this:

```
import { SpinnerModule } from '@b-software/vfg-styleguide-components';
```

The problem is, that I would like to use this form component in a project, where I do not have this package installed: '@b-software/vfg-styleguide-components', and I do not want to install this whole package there, because it is big, and I only need this one spinner from it.

I do not want to remove it, because in other projects I have this package installed, and I use more items from it.

How can I modify my form component to solve this problem?

My idea is, that I would remove the <ng-template #loadingTemplate> from the component, and implement it in the projects, where I want use it. But still, that would be code-duplication, and I am looking for a way better way to solve this. Can someone please help?